# Can't get extrinsic error from balances.sendTransfer extrinsic in polkadotJSAPI

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, error

I am doing error handling in an app using polkadotJSAPI 7.13.1
There are two ways to fetch info if an extrinsic succeeds or fails, the first one is via `dispatchError` in `signAndSend` like so

```
transferExtrinsic.signAndSend(account_from, { signer: injector.signer }, ({ status, events, dispatchError }) => {
```

The second is [described in docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/blocks/#how-do-i-map-extrinsics-to-their-events)

Both generally work for most extrinsics, but not for
`transferExtrinsic = api.tx.balances.transfer(account_to, (amount));,`
for example when trying to send more tokens than exists in a wallet. Both approaches give either DispatchError = undefined or doesn't find an event with extrinsicfailed. PolkadotJS web interface catches the error correctly. How do I check if any extrinsic succeeds or errors out, including balances.transfer extrinsic?

Comment: I'm facing an issue that When I'm using tx.utility.batchAll()
The message error has come. But it has just a message thrown 1-2s after the transaction is successful. I thought the transaction must be blocked and rollback but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by updating polkadotJSApi to v9, dispatchError seems to work in all cases in that version

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the code in a try-catch block:

```
try{
   await transferExtrinsic.signAndSend(injector.signer); 
}
catch(error: any){
    const errorMessage = error.toString();
    console.log(errorMessage);
}
```

And in the catch you get the error message, in your case you will get:

```
RpcError: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Inability to pay some fees , e.g. account balance too low
```

Comment: Thanks but, that too unfortunately, doesnt work universally. The extrinsic doesnt error out in js if it errors out on chain, for example when sending more tokens than you have in a wallet